# How to remove a unwanted gap in List of Tables in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am editing a word document and when I updated my list of tables, I got an unwanted gap in between two tables. I didn't do any editing with the tables.

Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lELKB.jpg)

Comment: That's a paragraph symbol. Did you try selecting it and hitting backspace?

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck in the check box in front of the display mark symbol, click OK after cancel, close the dialog box：

[image]